# How do I get a certain function to run whenever I initialize or at its creation a certain datatype in swift?

Tags: swift

I want that whenever there is any string type variable, trimmingCharacters function show run on it, and also if it's changed.
I have written String extension but still, I need to call it manually.

```swift
extension String
{
    func trim() -> String
    {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

I want when I do `var x=" hello"`. `x` should automatically be `hello` or when change `x = "jello "`, it should still return `jello` only.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve that on the built-in `String` type, but you can create your own `TrimmedString` type with a single `String` property and make sure that you trim the property during initialisation and in the property observer as well.

```
extension String {
    func trimmed() -> String {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}

struct TrimmedString {
    var value: String {
        didSet {
            value = value.trimmed()
        }
    }

    init(string: String) {
        value = string.trimmed()
    }
}
```

If you want to trim `UITextField.text`, you'll need to extend `UITextField` with a computed property.

```
extension UITextField {
    var trimmedText: String? {
        return text?.trimmed()
    }
}
```

Then whenever you would be calling `textField.text`, call `textField.trimmedText` instead.

Comment: is there any way I can incorporate this into UITextField to return TrimmedString.value only on calling .text ?

Comment: @ShcoobyDrool you'll need to create a computed property on UITextField that trims `.text`. Check my updated answer.